# Popup message on a right-click

Tags: javascript, html

When I click on a draggable cloneable `div` element, a simple popup message appears. How can I show this popup message only if it's a right-click while ignoring left-clicks?

```
<div id="drag-base" class="popup draggable" onclick="popupBaseDetails(this)">
  <span class="basepopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function popupBaseDetails(div) {
    div.querySelector(".basepopup").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`oncontextmenu="popupBaseDetails(this)"`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi2tMjE9pnUAhWKuY8KHUm1BQwQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FHTML%2FGlobal_attributes%2Fcontextmenu&usg=AFQjCNF45nYtVIO9gRNgu9VE8eNJvLofuw&sig2=Et3eVwYl-g2TFev2-ToUTA)  It will perform right click .

[`e.preventDefault()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi7x7u2-JnUAhVCK48KHbOXADYQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fevent.preventdefault%2F&usg=AFQjCNExzXG71FDK3YMwK9HzbdkgE3WlXQ&sig2=0mX-RYZ76ozP2MuGg9_VJQ) .it will prevent the default menu open on right click

**Updated**

```js
function popupBaseDetails(div,e) {
e.preventDefault()
  div.querySelector(".basepopup").classList.toggle("show");
}
```

```css
.show{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<div id="drag-base" class="popup draggable" oncontextmenu="popupBaseDetails(this,event)">
  <span class="basepopup">A Simple Popup!</span>
</div>
```